# Is there a way to prevent an application from being accidently closed in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I have my 3d printer application running while printing, if it is closed by accident the whole printing process needs to be started over. Got bitten two times already. Need an advice.

Comment: Also you may want to look into ways to avoid automatic software updates with reboots, for instance disabling the Windows Update service, while you are 3d printing.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't built-in functionality in Windows 10. However you might be able to accomplish this using third-party utilities. A quick search found me NoClose: https://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#NoClose